# the parser produces 403 even after specifying user-agent

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send request to this page atptour.com. But I get 403 error.

My full code:

```
    import requests as r   

    url = 'https://www.atptour.com/en/players/rafael-nadal/n409/overview'
    headers = {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
        # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.273238190.1601128735; ASP.NET_SessionId=qypv5nxmxn5fqv2jhybmtbdo; __cfduid=d93336273a6973e3e5d8650b14bcf16ff1610483237; _gid=GA1.2.1730400836.1611436986; __cf_bm=3f54264ddf1b98e724b5f986554cf9606e7d7a39-1611437005-1800-ATm3mfP/ROIlFEBkvw7fPt7U/QWeFDioKhgUvXv/uGGEkNngoWjZ+nWSZp/9pLEsufr/UYcZmz2QqxQx8Ic6RvswHvzutW6a0cm5Fc52k2UMDyfJXK5kCjMdeJat7Wg/0ay+25dV9GIZe22B3KlsrpIHGLARVb7FXWhwXiFGUyxC; atpModalContainer=%2Fen%2Fplayers%2Frafael-nadal%2Fn409%2Foverview; _ce.s=v11.rlc~1611337592298~v11slnt~1611437041966; _gat_UA-4616629-30=1',
        'referer': 'https://www.atptour.com/en/tournaments',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
    }
    session = r.Session()
    page = session.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Websites have gotten very smart at detecting bots/scripts and preventing them from accessing their sites.  My advice would be to try and use selenium and see if it works that way, and then if that works you can try headless mode.

Comment: If you clear browser cookies then trace a browser GET from the page using e.g. Telerik Fiddler or maybe the browser developer console network tab, you will see the exact headers it sends, then you can try to reproduce in your Python code. Don’t forget that a browser opening the page would retrieve every image and script mentioned in the HTML; you may have to do the same, and that’s when using a browser simulator like Selenium would reduce the difficulty for you.